# Restrict azure function to outgoing requests

Tags: azure, azure-functions, isolation

I need restrict my Functions in azure functionApp so they could't perform any  outgoing requests(like get forecast from website, get some data from Blob storage) so it will be fully isolated. How I can do it?

Answer (score 1):

For that you will need to use premium plan, add your function into network then in function app add application property `WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL=1` which will force to send outbound traffic via network where you can configure all security rules you want

[More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-networking-options#outbound-ip-restrictions)

Comment: is it possible also restrict access to file system So for example if at 1st invocation function created some file then it file won't be accessible in the next invocations of the function?

Comment: @NikolayKosarev i dont think its easy to do, if you write to blob storage then Azure function will have access to it. I think its better if you create new question with description what you try to achieve, since maybe its a bit simpler than you think